# How to view logs in Samsung Smart TV log viewer

Tags: eclipse, logging, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

In the Samsung Smart TV menu there is an option to `"Start receiving Smart TV logs"`. It's "OFF" by default.

When I clicked it I received a prompt to `"Check the Console View"`. I opened the console view and ran the app on emulator, but i couldn't see any logs there.

[image]

I know that when the emulator is launched, a separate window showing all the `alert("..");` logs is also launched.

I want to know how to use of this option of viewing logs via Console View. I'm new to Eclipse and Smart TV SDK. Is there anything that I'm missing?
How is this different from the logs that are already being shown with the emulator

Answer (score 0):

The console log is used for debugging in real devices.
Emulator already have it's own debugger console window so the emulator not sending anything to eclipse.

If you want to work with real devices this feature is very useful. Do app sync from TV to your workstation and enable the log receiver. When your synced apps run in the real devices (TV/BDP) the alert from application will sent to eclipse's console window

Comment: Thanks for the response @imkrisna...where is the "app sync" option? On TV or on Eclipse?

Comment: That's on TV. It's only available when you're logged in using 'develop' account

Comment: Could you tell me what version of sdk i should download for 2012 tv and how to connect it to tv to recive the developer app logs?

Answer (score 0):

The app will send its logs back to an active eclipse console on the system from which it downloaded the app.

I'm working with eclipse on windows, so I gave my pc a static ip address and installed the Apache 2.2 web server.  After uploading my app, I enable the console and open the console view as you did.  Then, I start my app, and I see all the log information in the console.

I find this log information essential, because some services return an error in the emulator, but actually execute successfully on the tv.  Many of these services are interacting directly with the tv hardware, and there is no other way to debug them.

Comment: Could you tell me what version of sdk i should download for 2012 tv and how to connect it to tv to recive the developer app logs?